# Will it harm my DSLR if I keep it on for a period of several years?

Tags: dslr, equipment-damage, timelapse

If I want to take one picture every 30 minutes (and don't get a live view from camera), can I keep my DSLR camera on during the day for two or three years?
I use an adapter instead of the camera's battery, so I haven't any problem in this area.

Comment: as long you turn off the function that turn the camera off over time, I would guess it should be ok. just remember to change the memory card

Comment: You can't change a memory card without turning the camera off.

Comment: I use it's tethering feature and photos will be saved on my computer directly.

Comment: A raspberry Pi may be worth looking into as the computer that the camera tethers to if you don't have a computer available already

Comment: @MichaelClark: I pull the SD card out on my Nikon DLSR while it's running with no issues. You shouldn't and you can't different things.

Comment: Doesn't the camera automatically shut down when you open the access door?

Comment: @MichaelClark no. My Nikon d40 (very old and simple, I know) allows you to open it and change it's card whithout turning it off.

Comment: @Michael: there is a tiny mecanical switch that when you open the access door, it jump up and turn the camera off. I use AC power instead of battery and just must hold it with a sharp object (something like a pen).

Comment: I also changed SD card in my D3100 while on without problems.. and no, it doesn't turn off, not even the display (if it was on to start with).

Comment: @aisa - None of the 3 dslr's I own shut down when you open the door and I'm guessing Michael's experience is the same.  Plus using tethering sidesteps the problem anyway.

Comment: I would venture that there are very few people, if any, that could conclusively answer this, as I highly doubt is part of the testing of the product.

Comment: @JamesSnell Every Canon DSLR I've ever owned shuts down if either the battery compartment door or memory card slot door is opened.

Comment: @MichaelClark - sorry, quoted wrong user - I meant woliveirajr.  Sounds like it might be a Canon thing as none of my Nikons ever did it.

Comment: Even if I *could* remove a memory card with the camera on, I probably *shouldn't* and certainly *wouldn't*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can keep your DSLR camera on for two or three years based on the following assumptions:

- Your particular model DSLR includes an option that allows you to disable any 'sleep' option that is enabled by the factory default settings.
- Your memory card has sufficient capacity to hold that many photos taken at the 'Image Quality' you have selected. Obviously, lower resolution and higher compression will allow you to store more images on the same card. Assuming 10MB per image, it would take a little over 170GB per year. File sizes of 500KB per image would only require 8.5GB per year.
- The camera is capable of being programmed to take an image once every 30 minutes, either internally or via a remote timer. In the case of the remote timer, the power supply of the timer would need to be sufficient to last the entire term of the project.
- Alternately, if your DSLR is capable you could shoot with the camera tethered to a computer with enough free storage space to store the image data. An option to transfer each image to the computer from the camera's image processor rather than storing it on the camera's memory card would be required. The computer would need to be sufficiently stable to run uninterrupted for the entire term of your project.
- The operating environment is within the manufacturer's recommendation, preferably near room temperature and the exposure time for each frame is typical at less than 30 seconds. If the exposure time is longer or the operating environment falls outside manufacturer recommended parameters, then the likelihood of issues would significantly increase.
- The electrical circuit supplying the camera's power adapter with current is uninterrupted for the entire term of your project. In the case of tethering, the same would be required of the circuit supplying power to the computer.

Comment: For your last point I'd probably tether to a laptop (ensuring it has no sleep/hibernate mode enabled) or to a computer running off some sort of UPS, and power the camera via the UPS to minimise any power cut threat.

Comment: thanks Michael. And another question: Would it damage the camera if I disable "sleep" option and keep it ON? any damage I mean. I don't know some thing like heating or damage the sensor or any thing else.

Comment: modern DSLR don't turn off, they are always running, just normally is a low power state. The power switch is just a message to turn the UI on, for example this can be seen by putting a SD card in the Nikon while it's off, and the green LED glows while it checks the card, or you put a battery int he camera, while off, if it a non-brand battery the UI pops up to tell you so. More to this, my friend leaves his Cannon turned on in his camera bag, always, and surprise it takes photos when the shutter is pressed.

Comment: Since your question already eliminated the use of Live View, that wasn't addressed in the answer. Any issues related to heat will be determined by the operating environment and exposure time for each image. If the operating environment is anywhere near room temperature and the exposure time for each frame is typical at less than 30 seconds, there should be no issues. If the exposure time is longer or the operating environment falls outside manufacturer recommended parameters, then the likelihood of issues would significantly increase.

Comment: Image sensors in most DSLRs are only energized slightly longer than the time it takes to take the picture. The shutter speed used would directly affect how long the sensor is energized per shot.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim I think we would both agree that when the question asks "... can I Keep my dSLR camera ON..." it is referring to fully powered up, not in a low power state.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim That must be an awful large camera bag if a cannon will fit in it.

Comment: Does it now, @SimeonPilgrim ;) https://256.makerslocal.org/2010/08/17/mini-cannon/

Comment: The title of this question is "Will it harm my DSLR?" and your answer starts with "Yes". The main issue is that the question actually deviates from its title, but you could easily slightly adapt your answer to make it more consistent for people taking a quick glance: "Yes, you can continuously shoot for 2-3 years, based on [...]"

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. You are correct I was addressing the body of the question, rather than the title.

Comment: You both are right. my title was "Can I..." and mattdm edit it into "Will it harm....".

Comment: Yes, I think I answered the question before @mattdm reversed the meaning of the headline with his edit.